# Run rules on the Sent Items folder

Tags: vba, outlook, rules

I have rules in Outlook for incoming and posted emails.

I found in the web the following routine which works for the emails which are in the 'INBOX'.

I am not able to use the GetRootFolder to select the 'Sent Items' folder.

The routine is the following:

```vb
Sub RunRules()

Dim st As Outlook.Store
Dim myRules As Outlook.rules
Dim rl As Outlook.Rule
Dim count As Integer
Dim k As Long
Dim fname As String
Dim currentcount As Integer
Dim prova As String
Dim numero As Integer
Dim prova1 As String
Dim Nrules As Integer
Dim objFolder, objNamespace, objOutlook, objFile
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
objNamespace.Logon "Default Outlook Profile", , False, False
numero = 1
' this is for the SENT Items
fname = "I"
count = 1
k = 1
 Set rl = Nothing
 Set st = Nothing
 Set myRules = Nothing
'On Error Resume Next
   ' get default store (where rules live)
  Set st = Application.Session.DefaultStore
   Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder (olFolderSentMail)
   ' get rules
   Set myRules = st.GetRules
   For k = 1 To myRules.count ' might be 0-based, didnt check

On Error Resume Next
Set rl = Nothing
Set rl = myRules(k)
    If rl.RuleType = olRuleReceive Then         'determine if it’s an Inbox rule, if so, run it
 ' I selecto just the rules that are for the sent ITEMS
      prova = rl.Name
      prova1 = Left(prova, 1)
      If prova1 = fname Then
        rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True
         objFile.WriteLine rl.Name
         count = count + 1
          prova = ""
          prova1 = ""
     End If
End If
Next
  Set rl(count) = Nothing
  Set st = Nothing
  Set myRules = Nothing
  Set objFolder = Nothing
  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I did not notice your question before.

I have not tried your code.  Instead I show an extract from one of my routines which moves selected properties to variables from every mail item in the Sent Items folders.

Hope this helps.

```
Dim FolderTgt As MAPIFolder
Dim HtmlBody As String
Dim InxItemCrnt As Long
Dim ReceivedTime As Date
Dim SenderEmailAddress As String
Dim SenderName As String
Dim Subject As String
Dim TextBody As String
Dim FolderTgt As MAPIFolder

Set FolderTgt = CreateObject("Outlook.Application"). _
                GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

For InxItemCrnt = FolderTgt.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
  With FolderTgt.Items.Item(InxItemCrnt)
    If .Class = olMail Then
      ' Save selected data to variables
      ReceivedTime = .ReceivedTime
      Subject = .Subject
      SenderName = .SenderName
      SenderEmailAddress = .SenderEmailAddress
      TextBody = .Body
      HtmlBody = .HtmlBody
    End If
  End With
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless specified, rules run on the Inbox of the default store, regardless of the store with the rules.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RunRules()

Dim st As Store
Dim myRules As rules
Dim rl As Rule

Dim count As Long
Dim k As Long

Dim fname As String
Dim prova As String
Dim prova1 As String

Dim objFolder As Folder

' this is for the SENT Items
fname = "I"

' get store (can be any store)
Set st = Session.defaultStore

' get rules from specified store
Set myRules = st.GetRules()

' The default folder is the Inbox of the default store,
'  regardless of the store with the rules.
Set objFolder = st.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Debug.Print "objFolder: " & objFolder

For k = 1 To myRules.count
    
    Set rl = myRules(k)

    Debug.Print rl.RuleType ' 0 = olRuleReceive, 1 = olRuleSend
    
    If rl.RuleType = olRuleSend Then
    
        ' rule name starting with "I"
        prova = rl.name
        prova1 = Left(prova, 1)
        If prova1 = fname Then
            ' Designate a folder if not the Inbox of the default store
            rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=objFolder
            count = count + 1
        End If
        
    End If
    
Next

Debug.Print count & " rules processed"

End Sub
```